# Issue with FDF on different platforms PDFTron

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdftron

I am facing an issue wherein I am unable to show annotations on my PDF on IOS device that are made from some other platforms e.g web, Windows or android. What is actually happening is if I am editing an already created annotation like an underline by changing the notes associated with it from my iOS device, then it is not reflecting on other platforms.

On further Investigation, I found that the PDF format generated by PDFTRON on iOS is different from the format generated by PDFTRON on any other platform. For example, I draw an underline annotation on a document from the web. The initial FDF received is as follows:

```
<squiggly subject="Squiggly" page="0" rect="275.93,656.703203,336.2084,665.759453" flags="print" name="0eabf5b2-77ab-4c04-3379-438e7a8fc714" title="testuser" date="D:20161027122930+05'30'" color="#FF0000" opacity="1" creationdate="D:20161027121425+05'30'" coords="275.93,665.76,336.21,665.76,275.93,656.7,336.21,656.7"><contents-richtext><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:spec="2.0.2" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:10.1.3"><p dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal">under_line</span></p></body></contents-richtext><contents>under_line</contents><popup flags="print,nozoom,norotate" page="0" rect="0,692,150,792" open="no"/></squiggly>
```

I  have entered the text under_line in the notes initially. Now when I edit this annotation from the web (Changing the text from under_line to under_lines) , the resulting FDF is as follows:

```
<squiggly subject="Squiggly" page="0" rect="275.93,656.703203,336.2084,665.759453" flags="print" name="0eabf5b2-77ab-4c04-3379-438e7a8fc714" title="testuser" date="D:20161027122930+05'30'" color="#FF0000" opacity="1" creationdate="D:20161027121425+05'30'" coords="275.93,665.76,336.21,665.76,275.93,656.7,336.21,656.7"><contents-richtext><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:spec="2.0.2" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:10.1.3"><p dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal">under_lines</span></p></body></contents-richtext><contents>under_lines</contents><popup flags="print,nozoom,norotate" page="0" rect="0,692,150,792" open="no"/></squiggly>
```

The same annotation when edited from an iOS device produces the following FDF:

```
<squiggly subject="Squiggly" page="0" rect="275.93,656.703203,336.2084,665.759453" flags="print" name="0eabf5b2-77ab-4c04-3379-438e7a8fc714" title="testuser" date="D:20161027122930+05'30'" color="#FF0000" opacity="1" creationdate="D:20161027121425+05'30'" coords="275.93,665.76,336.21,665.76,275.93,656.7,336.21,656.7"><contents-richtext><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:spec="2.0.2" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:10.1.3"><p dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal">under_line</span></p></body></contents-richtext><contents>under_lines</contents><popup flags="print,nozoom,norotate" page="0" rect="0,692,150,792" open="no"/></squiggly>
```

Now you can see the difference. When I edit the text on the web, the text is changed at both points wherever it appears while when it is changed from the iOS device , the text is updated at only one place.

I believe this is causing a problem for me. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you post an example of the difference? Or provide more detail on what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation can actually have two Contents. The regular one, and a Rich Contents (essentially a minimal subset of HTML). The two are not guaranteed to be the same, which is the case here. One field got updated, the other didn't, as this actually depends on the specific PDF software used.

There is no difference between our different SDK's in this regards, so either you used two different files, or two different PDF readers. It sounds like on iOS used a 3rd party program.

Comment: I have verified that the files are same. What do you mean by different PDF readers?

Comment: That one PDF Reader might display Rich-Contents, and then also modify that entry, without updating Contents, or vice-versa. Then another program might display the Contents entry (not the Rich-Contents) entry, and therefore show the older original contents. Typically you don't see this, as most PDF editors create the appearance anyway, which other readers simply read (that is they read the appearance, instead of generating their own appearance based on either Contents or Rich-Contents).

Comment: I believe there is no difference in PDF readers as well then. Both the platforms are using the PDFTron reader. No 3rd party program is being used.